# Move a CSV file to another directory

Tags: php, csv, copy, save, rename

I am trying to move a file from the command directory it currently sits in to a new directory called product_upload however the code below does not work properly

```
 //The following creates and saves the file in the directory - this bit works fine. It saves the file in the command directory

  $file = fopen($filenamecsv, "w+");

fwrite($file,$contents); 

 fclose($file);
```

////The following does not work

```
$filenamecsv_move = "command/Product_category_list".date("j-m-Y_H.i"). ".csv";  
$filenamecsv2_move = "command/product_upload/Product_category_list".date("j-m-Y_H.i"). ".csv";  

rename($filenamecsv_move ,$filenamecsv2_move );
```

Comment: yes I have copied them exactly

Comment: does the function returns FALSE? perhaps haven's writing permissions in the moving directory. Can you check the folder by [**is_writeable**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

Comment: Please check for the file permission.

Comment: Thank you was just the file permissions

Answer (score 0):

Probably directory `command/product_upload` doesn't exists and rename function won't create it. In this case you have to manually create this directory or add mkdir in your script.

Look at below script. If you have only command directory and commend mkdir line rename function won't rename file and return false (var_dump added at the end).

```
<?php

$filenamecsv_move = "command/Product_category_list".date("j-m-Y_H.i"). ".csv";  

file_put_contents($filenamecsv_move,'testdata');

$filenamecsv2_move = "command/product_upload/Product_category_list".date("j-m-Y_H.i"). ".csv";  

if (!file_exists('command/product_upload')) {
   mkdir('command/product_upload', true);
}


$result = rename($filenamecsv_move ,$filenamecsv2_move ); 

var_dump($result);
```

You should also turn on error_reporting to display errors when you are testing your script. I had the following warning:

> Warning:
>   rename(command/Product_category_list29-05-2014_13.40.csv,command/product_upload/Product_category_list29-05-2014_13.40.csv):
>   in D:\DaneAplikacji\WampServer\www\rename\index.php on line 12